# SIG error during global destruction

Tags: perl, signals, runtime-error

I have an issue with a script I created. This is the first time I use signal as I would like my script to run like a daemon, so I set several signal Handler to properly end my script :

```
local $SIG{HUP} = \&StopSuperviser;
local $SIG{INT} = \&StopSuperviser;
local $SIG{QUIT} = \&StopSuperviser;
local $SIG{ILL} = \&StopSuperviser;
local $SIG{ABRT} = \&StopSuperviser;
local $SIG{TERM} = \&StopSuperviser;
```

This is working properly but when I send one of those signal to my script (Crt-C, kill -15, kill -1 ...) the StopSuperviser function is correctly called but I always receive the following error in my script's output:

> Argument "HUP" isn't numeric in null operation during global destruction.

I have searched on google but I didn't find anything dealing with this behavior.

May someone put some light in this?

Thanks you very much for your help

Best Regards

Florent

#

Thanks four your replies, here is the StopSuperviser Function:

```
sub StopSuperviser
{
    print "On quite\n";
    $StopAlarm = 1;
    &DeleteThreadOrder($AllProcess);
    foreach my $Subprocess (@$AllProcess) {
        foreach my $thread (@{$Subprocess->{Thread}}) {
            $thread->kill('USR1');
            $thread->join();
        }
    }
    exit;
}
```

I also use the following package :

```
use Alarm::Concurrent;
```

This may important to know, or may not :)
Hope this help :)

Thanks again for your response and help

Best Regards

Florent

Comment: Please show us the contents of `sub StopSuperviser`.

Comment: Good point, @Peter, perhaps he's misusing `$_[0]`.

Comment: @ikegami That was my suspicion, but we need to see the code to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I have update my post with the informations you asked. I don't use $_[0] in my script, I use $0 but this is not the same and I don't think this can be related

Comment: Hello, is my update helpfull to understand this problem? Otherwise, may someone explain me what mecanism can cause this error so I can check my whole code to try to fix this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem earlier this year, and ended up finding the solution on PerlMonks, but I can't find the link now. I'll update if I come across it. Their explanation was much more detailed than what I present here.

It's an expression of a feature described in perlsub:

> If a subroutine is called using the & form, the argument list is
>   optional, and if omitted, no @_ array is set up for the subroutine:
>   the @_ array at the time of the call is visible to subroutine instead.

If memory serves, you should be able to fix it by changing:

```
local $SIG{HUP} = \&StopSuperviser;
```

to

```
local $SIG{HUP} = sub { StopSuperviser() };
```

Comment: Hello, thx a lot for your help. I have changed my code like you suggested but this doesn't solved my problem. I will be happy to read the solution you got on Perlmonks if you find it again ;)